# OOPHP not working; array issue

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Now I am getting this message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xampp\htdocs\dackhotell\includes\form.php on line 39 and I really don't understand (I am new at PHP) how to solve it.

Here is the code for the files:

```
    <?php
            if (isset($_REQUEST["updateView"])){
                $id = $_REQUEST["updateView"];
                $obj = $register->getOrder($id);
        ?>
    <p>

    <!-- Formuläret för uppdateringen -->
    Inlämningsid: <input type = "text" name = "deliverId" value = "<?php echo $id;?>" readonly /><br />
    Namn: <input type="text" name="new_name" value="<?php echo $obj->getName()?>" />
    Telefonnummer: <input type="tel" name="new_phone_number" value="<?php echo $obj->getPhone()?>" />
    E-post: <input type="email" name="new_email_user" value="<?php echo $obj->getEmail()?>" />
    Däckfabrikat och dimension: <input type="text" name="new_fabricDim" value="<?php echo $obj->getDim()?>" />
    Status: <input type="text" name="new_status" value="<?php echo $obj->getStatus()?>">
    <br />

    <input type="submit" name="updateOrder" value="Uppdatera info" />
    <input type="button" id="exit" value="Avbryt" onClick="history.back()" />
    </p>
    <!-- ********** -->
        <?php
        }


        foreach($register->gethotelList() as $key => $obj){
            echo "<br /><strong>Namn: </strong>" . $obj->getName() . " <strong>Telefonnummer: </strong>" . $obj->getPhone() . 
            " <strong>E-post: </strong>" . $obj->getEmail() . " <strong>Däckfabrikat och dimension: </strong>" . $obj->getDim() . 
            " <strong>Status: </strong>" . $obj->getStatus() . " <strong>Uppdaterat: </strong>" . $obj->getDatum() . 
            " <a href='index.php?delOrder=$key'>Ta bort</a>, <a href='index.php?updateView=$key'> Uppdatera</a>";
        }
        ?>
```

And the OOP file or code is as this:

```
// Skapar klassen Register som används sedan i formen

class Register {
    protected $name = '';
    // Skapar en array där all information kommer att lagras i HotelList
    public $hotelList = array();


    function __construct($namn){
        $this->name = $namn;

        /* Kollar ifall filen existerar och unserializerar det
        sedan till array HotelList som består av objekt */
        if(file_exists("order/order.txt")>0)
            $this->hotelList = unserialize(file_get_contents("order/order.txt"));
    }

    // Skapar en funktion som lägger till nya order till array
    function addOrder($userName, $userPhone, $userEmail, $fabricDim, $userStatus, $dat){
        $this->hotelList[] = new Order($userName, $userPhone, $userEmail, $fabricDim, $userStatus, $dat);

        // Serializerar och lägger till innehållet av array till nämnda filen
        file_put_contents("order/order.txt",serialize($this->hotelList));
    }

    //Skapar en funktion för att kunna ta bort en order
    function removeOrder($ind){
        unset($this->hotelList[$ind]);

        // Serialiserar och lägger till innehållet av array till nämnda filen
        file_put_contents("order/order.txt",serialize($this->hotelList));
    }

    // Skapar en funktion för att kunna uppdatera innehållet eller ordern
    function updateOrder($ind, $userName, $userPhone, $userEmail, $fabricDim, $userStatus, $dat){
        $this->hotelList[$ind] = new Order($userName, $userPhone, $userEmail, $fabricDim, $userStatus, $dat);

        // Serialiserar innehållet och lägger till den uppdaterade informationen till listan
        file_put_contents("order/order.txt",serialize($this->hotelList));
    }
    public function getHotelList(){
        return $this->hotelList;
    }
    public function getOrder($ind){
        return $this->HotelList[$ind];
    }
}

?>
```

Now did I miss somewhere to proclaim something as array or what should I do acctually?

Comment: What line is line 39 in `form.php`?

Comment: I don't see `<form></form>` tags anywhere. Plus, no way of knowing how you're using/calling the `Register` class. And where's the `Order` class? Too many unknowns here.

Comment: Take it up with the answer given below. You don't seem to be in a hurry for this.

Comment: First, please don't include methods and bunches of codes that aren't related to your question, it's hard to understand. Second, please dump your `getHotelList()` output.

Answer (score 1):

without checking it to much, i think you have a typo with the function name. The function name in the register class is getHotelList not gethotelList.

So try changing

```
foreach($register->gethotelList() as $key => $obj){
```

to

```
foreach($register->getHotelList() as $key => $obj){
```

Comment: Actually, [PHP "function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration"](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php). I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'am guessing the issue is somewhere with this line in the constructor:

```
        $this->hotelList = unserialize(file_get_contents("order/order.txt"));
```

unserialize returns false if an error happend. I would start there.